# When and how Android System write the process infos into file /proc/?

Tags: android, linux

As we all know, the running process infos are saved in the catalog '/proc/'. Does anyone know When and how Android System write the running process infos into file /proc/?

Comment: I would suggest you to add Linux tag too, as this is related to linux kernel